# Group By (Name) and Order By (Date) for two select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a sort of large query which contains a inner select query. My objective is to group all the records by field call Product Number (which is not unique and appears multiple times) and then by the Date.

I added the Order By date at the end of the query and seems to work fine. The query generated all the records in order of the Date but the records are not grouped by the ProductNumber.

Here is a visual sample of the data

```
ProductId   Manufacturer        ProductNumber       Date
1           Kellog                H1            05/05/2017
5           Nestle                H1            05/01/2017
8           Nutmeg                H1            04/30/2017
9           Highland              H3            04/09/2017
10          Houston               H1            04/15/2017
11          Miami                 H3            04/12/2017
```

I am trying to get the output to look like the following

```
ProductId   Manufacturer        ProductNumber       Date
1           Kellog                H1            05/05/2017
5           Nestle                H1            05/01/2017
8           Nutmeg                H1            04/30/2017
10          Houston               H1            04/15/2017
9           Highland              H3            04/09/2017
11          Miami                 H3            04/12/2017
```

So, how would I group by a column field (ProductNumber) with group by and then order by Date?
In the query, I added the Order by Date. When I added the group by ProductNumber, the error message is asking me add all the fields in the inner select to the group by. Do I really need to all all the fields(there are lot of them in the real query) in the select to my group by? There must be a better solution.

Here is my query (just a sample) so far

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 *,
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT NP.ManufacuturerId,
                        C.ManufacuturerName,
                        IR2.ProductNumber,
                        NP.Field1,
                        NP.Field2,
                        NP.Field3,
                        NP.Field4,
                        CN.C2Date                     CN.CompanyNotificationId,
                        NPR.NotificationProcessName,
                        Cast(NP.CompanyId AS VARCHAR(15))
                        + NPR.NotificationProcessName AS 'CompanyIdAndProcess',
                        CC.UserId,
                        NT.NotificationTypeName,
                        CC.EmailAddress,
                        IsRegistered = CASE
                                         WHEN C.IsRegistered = 1 THEN 'Yes'
                                         ELSE 'No'
                                       END,
        FROM   ProductDetails NP
               INNER JOIN Manufactuers C
                       ON C.ManufacuturerId = NP.ManufacturerId) Q
ORDER  BY CN.C2DateDESC;
```

Comment: What would be the result if the `11      Miami           H3          04/12/2017` date was `05/05/2017` ?

Comment: isn't that logical when you group by product number & selecting some other columns in the select query should be aggregated? there are different aggregated functions we have in SQL like min, max, Avg etc. you can use them in a select query as per your requirements or you can group by those columns.

Answer (score 3):

What you are calling "grouping" is really ordering.

Order by ProductNumber, Date.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are trying to order by a field that is included inside the grouped data, and is not always the same, example:

```
1       Kellog          H1          05/05/2017
5       Nestle          H1          05/01/2017
```

If you group by `ProductNumber` and *after* the grouping you want to sort by date, is very likely that your database engine will not know by which value to order by (May 5th or May 1st?). So what you will need to do is to specify which value to use when grouping, for example with a MAX or MIN function.

Quick sample:

```
SELECT   Count(*) AS Products, ProductNumber, MAX(Date) AS maxdate
FROM     Table
GROUP BY ProductNumber
ORDER BY maxdate;
```